# How to replace placeholder in C# using string.format?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, .net-core, string.format

I have an oData api url where I am trying to replace querystring values with dynamic values.
I wish to pass comma separated string to one of my placeholder but I am getting error: 
**"Input string is not in correct format".**

Here, in my **"$select"** placeholder I am passing comma separated string but it's failing with above error.

**Here is my code:**

```
string test = string.Format("https://myapiUrl/views/my_view_name?$filter=customer_id eq {} & $select={}", "101", "price,createdOn");
```

Can anybody guide me on this ?
Thanks !!!

Comment: You need to add the index number in your braces.

Comment: Try this with `string.format`: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.string.format?view=net-5.0

Comment: Or try this with `$ - string interpolation`: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/tokens/interpolated

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
string test = string.Format("https://myapiUrl/views/my_view_name?$filter=customer_id eq {0} & $select={1}", "101", "price,createdOn");
```

Have to add the number of the index of the parameter to the curly braces. (zero based)